# SQLDateTime from a time column is missing the milliseconds component

Tags: databaselink

Can anyone confirm this?

I am using M9.0.1 on win7 64bit connecting to a SQL Server db.  When I fetch a datetime column the SQLDateTime objects contain 6 entries, 5 integers and a fractional second component.  When I fetch a date the SQLDateTime objects contain 3 integers.  When I fetch a time column there are 3 integer entries even though that column contains times with millisecond components that are not zero.